# Adding a custom tab page

Tags: vb.net, user-controls, tabcontrol, tabpage

I inherited code that was programmed somewhere around 10 years ago in VB. The TabControl and TabPage that was used is custom, and I need to add another TabPage to it. The problem is, when I right-click, and select Add Tab, or add the page to the Collection, I get a Windows Forms Tab Page instead of the custom tab page that I need.

I have checked the Designer code for the class, and the other 5 tabs that were there previously are added in it, so I know they were added using the UI. Since I have no experience with custom tabs, I'm not sure if adding a new page is the same with any custom Tab Control, or if the method of adding a new page is different for each. I'm trying to keep the code consistent, so I'm wanting to add the tab using the designer, but I

I do need to use the Custom TabPage rather than the default Windows Forms TabPage since code elsewhere makes use of the custom functions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

I manually added the tab and controls, so I could continue working, but I am still interested in a solution, since I am sure I will need to add additional tabs in the future.

Comment: You could copy and paste the code for one of the existing tabs, in the designer file

Comment: @peterG: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately, that appears to be what I am going to have to do. I can't place it in the Designer, since it will get overwritten, but I can put a new method to add additional tabs in the Control. It seems like a very unclean and inconsistent way to do it, but right now it is looking like the only way.

Comment: It won't necessarily get overwritten. Close the gui designer first then open the designer file and modify the code.

Comment: Have you tried adding the tab by dropping it from the toolbox?

Comment: @tinstaafl: I did think of that, but the TabPage does not show up in the Toolbox.

Comment: Is there a reference to an unfamiliar item that looks like it might be a tab control in your references?  maybe something like "jacksonsoft.customtabcontrol"?

Comment: Or if the class is inside one of the files separating into it's own file might help.